# Painting every image inside a folder

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a set of 50 images inside a folder where i'd like to draw black blocks or thick lines once at 10 different possible locations in row and column wise, for every image inside a folder. For example:

[image]

For every image inside a folder, i would like to draw just one black block randonly at those positions for every image inside a folder and save them.

Currently, i am loading my images and drawing them one by one, like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage
source_img = img.resize((81, 150))


def loadImages(path):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        arr = np.array(img)
        loadedImages.append(arr)


    return loadedImages 

images = loadImages(path)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle(((0, 0), (100, 50)), fill="black")
source_img.save('drawnimage.jpg', "JPEG")
```

Basically my goal is to automate this task: load every image inside a folder and draw just one block randomly at these rows and columns in the loaded image and save them after, instead of doing it one by one image like i am doing right now.

Using the answer by the user below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from os import listdir
import random

def block_image_portions(path):
    filepath_list = listdir(path)
    for filepath in filepath_list:
        img = Image.open(path + filepath)
        img = DrawRandom(img)
        img.save('C:/Users/Occlusion/')


def DrawRandom(img):
    partitions = ((0, 0), (40, 20)), ((0, 22), (40, 40)), ((0, 40), (40, 60)), ((0, 40), (40, 60)), ((1, 65), (41, 84)), ((2, 86), (41, 107)), ((1, 130), (40, 145)), ((40, 0), (80, 25)), ((40, 30), (80, 50)), ((40, 50), (80, 70)), ((40, 75), (80, 95)), ((40, 100), (80, 115)), ((40, 120), (80, 135)), ((40, 140), (75, 150))          
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.rectangle(random.choice(partitions), fill="black")
    return img


block_image_portions('C:/Users/images/')
```

> ValueError: unknown file extension:

at

> img.save('C:/Users/Occlusion/')

Comment: You didn't mention which directory the images are stored in, nor how their names look, nor what format they are in, nor how you want the results saved, nor why you show a colour result when your code appears to change your image to greyscale, nor why your result is 225x225 pixels when your code appears to resize to 150x81 pixels...

Comment: it didnt matter honestly, my main focus was how to paint images, i think its fairly explained above, see how Krish's answer made a huge difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with your program so far:

- You are loading all images at once (bad for memory) in `loadImages`
- Inconsistent naming scheme leads to typos like this:

```
images = loadImages(path)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
```

The required code is something like the following:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from os import listdir


def block_image_portions(path):
    filepath_list = listdir(path)
    for filepath in filepath_list:
        img = Image.open(path + filepath)
        img = DrawRandom(img)
        img.save(filepath)


def DrawRandom(img):
    # add code to randomly draw rectangle
    return img
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Krish's answer as reference the way to do this was:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from os import listdir
import random



def block_image_portions(path):
    filepath_list = listdir(path)
    for filepath in filepath_list:
        img = Image.open(path + filepath)
        img = img.resize((81, 150))
        img = DrawRandom(img)
        img.save('C:/Users/paint/'+filepath, 'JPEG')


def DrawRandom(img):
    partitions = ((0, 0), (40, 20)), ((0, 22), (40, 40)), ((0, 40), (40, 60)), ((0, 40), (40, 60)), ((1, 65), (41, 84)), ((2, 86), (41, 107)), ((1, 130), (40, 145)), ((40, 0), (80, 25)), ((40, 30), (80, 50)), ((40, 50), (80, 70)), ((40, 75), (80, 95)), ((40, 100), (80, 115)), ((40, 120), (80, 135)), ((40, 140), (75, 150))          
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.rectangle(random.choice(partitions), fill="black")
    return img


block_image_portions('C:/Users/imgs-to-be-painted/')
```